# Call same queuetrigger function for multiple queues in parallel

Tags: azure, webjob, queuetrigger

I  am creating multiple queues dynamically like workbook1, workbook2...workbook100. 
I have written one queuetrigger function which needs to be trigger for all the queues created dynamically once any message arrive

I want to trigger same trigger function in parallel whenever there is message in multiple queues.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a method to implement your requirements directly. Because you can only bind one trigger to the same function:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#overview

However, you can copy the same function with different triggers even it's an unwise way. Or you could try the `Precompiled functions` referred to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820961/10383250).

If you still have questions , please let me know.

Comment: @Sandip if my answer could help you, could you accept my answer.Thanks.